# Normalizing/integrating a product of two exponentials

Tags: integration, quantum-mechanics

In Griffith's Intro to QM Problem 1.5, I'm asked to normalize the wave function:

$\psi ( x,t) =Ae^{-\lambda |x|} e^{-i\omega t}$ (where $A$, $\lambda$ and $\omega$ are positive, real constants)

I know that this means solving for $A$ where:

$1=\int |\psi |^{2} dx$

According to the solutions this reduces to:

$2|A|^{2}\int ^{\infty }_{0} e^{-2\lambda x}dx$

...but I don't understand why!

1) Why does the $e^{-i\omega t}$ term disappear? Is it because $t$ is (treated as) constant? (If it was considered to be $0$, that would explain it, but that seems unreasonable given the definition of $\psi$?)

2) Is the 0 - $\infty$ limit of the integral due to the $|x|$ in the exponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\psi|^2 \, \text{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |Ae^{- \lambda |x|}|^2\cdot|e^{-i \omega t}|^2 \, \text{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |A|^2e^{-2\lambda |x|} \, \text{d}x$$
Since, $e^{-i \omega t}$ is a number with magnitude $1$(try Euler's formula).
Now,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |A|^2e^{-2\lambda |x|} \, \text{d}x = |A|^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2\lambda |x|} \, \text{d}x = 2|A|^2 \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2\lambda x} \, \text{d}x$$
By symmetry, replacing $|x| \mapsto x$ and considering the integral on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Got it—Euler's formula was what I was missing. And now I see what you mean by symmetry and the factor of 2! Do you know why, though, one would want to change the limits from $-\infty - \infty$ to $0 - \infty$?

Comment: Ease of computation. How else do you go about computing an integral involving $|x|$?